# AES 128 with CBC In IOS

Tags: objective-c, commoncrypto

```
+ (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt // kCCEncrypt or kCCDecrypt
               error:(NSError **)error
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       0, //kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       symmetricKey.bytes,
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes,
                       dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes,
                       dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    }
    else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kEncryptionError"
                                         code:ccStatus
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        dataOut = nil;
    }

    return dataOut;
}
```

I have dataIn as 154 bytes of Data, key and Iv having 16 bytes of data when i am doing encryption it is giving -4303 error.(AES128 With CBC In IOS)

Comment: Alignment error means there is something wrong with the sizes. Please check my answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921254/aes-ecb-ios-encrypt/48559334#48559334

Answer (score 0):

Error code -4303 is kCCAlignmentError. From documentation:

> When decrypting, or when encrypting with a block cipher with padding
>   disabled, kCCAlignmentError will be returned if the total number of
>   bytes provided to CCCryptUpdate() is not an integral multiple of the
>   current algorithm's block size.

You should check if your input data size is correct.